# How to assign an output of a module with variable?

Tags: verilog

I have the problem that i dont know how I can assign an output from my selfmade 16-Bit Right Shifter with a variable from my ALU. I am new to Verilog so please be kind.(^^)
Also I am not sure if its correct how i connected my things....
For the finalbitshifter I used 4 shifter with each 16 muxes, as the excercise requires this and the finalbitshifter works, so this is not problem.
(Sorry for my bad english)

The code part:

```
  // selecting operation of ALU:
reg [3:0] aluop;
  always @(opc)
    begin
      if (opc==0)         aluop = 0; // HLT
      else if (opc==1)    aluop = 1; // ADD
      else if (opc==2)    aluop = 2; // SUB
      else if (opc==3)    aluop = 3; // AND
      else if (opc==4)    aluop = 4; // XOR
      else if (opc==5)    aluop = 5; // SHL
      else if (opc==6)    aluop = 6; // SHR
      else if (opc==7)    aluop = 0; // LDA
      else if (opc==8)    aluop = 0; // LD
      else if (opc==9)    aluop = 0; // ST
      else if (opc=='hA)  aluop = 7; // LDI
      else if (opc=='hB)  aluop = 7; // STI
      else if (opc=='hC)  aluop = 0; // BZ
      else if (opc=='hD)  aluop = 0; // BP
      else if (opc=='hE)  aluop = 0; // JR
      else if (opc=='hF)  aluop = 7; // JL
    end
  // #TODO
  // ALU: 
  //reg [15:0] alu;

  wire [15:0] outputwire;
  finalbitshifter bitshifter(alu_A, outputwire, alu_B[3:0]);

  always @(alu_A or alu_B or aluop)
    begin

    if      (aluop==0)    alu <= alu_A;
    else if (aluop==1)    alu <= alu_A + alu_B;
    else if (aluop==2)    alu <= alu_A - alu_B;
    else if (aluop==3)    alu <= alu_A & alu_B;
    else if (aluop==4)    alu <= alu_A ^ alu_B;   
    else if (aluop==5)    alu <= alu_A << alu_B[3:0];
    else if (aluop==6)    alu <= outputwire;
    else if (aluop==7)    alu <= alu_B;

    $display("OutW: OW %b, ALU %b, ALUA %b, ALUB %b, OPC %b", outputwire, alu, alu_A, alu_B, aluop);

    end  
   endmodule



module finalbitshifter(input1, output1, selector);

  input [15:0] input1;
  input [3:0] selector;

  output [15:0] output1;

  wire [15:0] output_to_second;
  wire [15:0] output_to_third;
  wire [15:0] output_to_fourth;

  wire aolout_to_second;
  wire aolout_to_third;
  wire aolout_to_fourth;

  //bitshift1(in_to_mux, mux_to_out, sel0, aolout);
  bitshift1 bit1(input1, output_to_second, selector[0], aolout_to_second);
  //bitshift2(aolin, in_to_mux, mux_to_out, sel0, aolout);
  bitshift2 bit2(aolout_to_second, output_to_second, output_to_third, selector[1], aolout_to_third);
  //bitshift4(aolin, in_to_mux, mux_to_out, sel0, aolout);
  bitshift4 bit4(aolout_to_third, output_to_third, output_to_fourth, selector[2],aolout_to_fourth);
  //bitshift8(aolin, in_to_mux, mux_to_out, sel0);
  bitshift8 bit8(aolout_to_fourth, output_to_fourth, output1, selector[3]);


endmodule
```

Comment: i made a 16Bit Right Shifter in a module and want to insert instead of outputwire at "alu <= outputwire" because this doesnt work as it should. The compiler says that it wants a task or function, but i cant put my module in a task or function...so i dont know how to do it with my 3-days-verilog-knowledge...^^

Comment: Why are you using non-blocking (`<=`) to assign `alu`? It is combinational logic; it should be with blocking (`=`) assignment. Also `outputwire` needs to be added the the sensitivity list, **_or_** use an auto-sensitivity list `@*` (preferred).

Comment: @Hungryapeman What is the compiler error? Did you changed non-blocking assignments to blocking assignments as suggested by Greg?

Comment: We got the code from our prof. so we only are allowed to change the things we should, but you thanks alot  @Greg i had to add outputwire to the sensitivity list, now it works how it should!

Answer (score 0):

`outputwire` is missing from the sensitivity list. This will not impact synthesis, but it often leads to inaccurate behavior in simulation.

```
always @(alu_A or alu_B or aluop or outputwire)
```

A cleaner solution would be use an auto-sensitivity list `@*` or the synonymous `@(*)`. Auto-sensitivity is a IEEE 1364-2001 (aka Verilog-2001) enhancement. The Verilog-95 (IEEE 1364-1995) style is still support but discouraged; as it is prone to issues like you are experiencing. Verilog-2001 style is preferred (SystemVerilog's `always_comb` is even better).

```
always @*
```

---

Non-blocking (`<=`) *should* be used to assign synchronous logic (flops and latches). Blocking (`=`) *should* be used to assign combinational logic. This is a guideline, not a rule. Be aware there is a risk of race conditions in simulation if you do not follow the guideline (similar type of issue with the incomplete sensitivity list).

As toolic pointed out, it is recommenced to use `case-endcase` instead of those `if-else` statements when stepping through the `opc` and `aluop` conditions.